# Why don't I have permission to read files on the CD I bought?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, filesystem, cd, cd-drive

I recently bought [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123747503), which came with an accompanying CD. When I try to view the contents of the CD in Ubuntu, I don't have read permission for any of the files. `ls -al` in the root of the CD gives this:

```
dr-x------ 1 mpiroc mpiroc  4096 Sep 21  2011 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root    4096 Sep  1 18:23 ../
---xr-Sr-- 1 mpiroc mpiroc  3799 Sep 14  2011 advanced-content-and-appe.html*
---xr-Sr-- 1 mpiroc mpiroc    24 Sep 20  2008 autorun.bat*
--w---S--- 1 mpiroc mpiroc    48 May 18  2004 autorun.inf
--w---S--- 1 mpiroc mpiroc 12344 May 14  2004 cd-small.bmp
--w---S--- 1 mpiroc mpiroc  4090 Sep 14  2011 historical-perspectives-a.html
dr-x------ 1 mpiroc mpiroc  2048 Sep  6  2011 images/
--w---S--- 1 mpiroc mpiroc  1798 Sep 14  2011 index.html
--w---S--- 1 mpiroc mpiroc  5990 Sep 15  2011 readme.txt
dr-x------ 1 mpiroc mpiroc  2048 Sep  6  2011 resources/
dr-x------ 1 mpiroc mpiroc  2048 Sep  6  2011 search/
--w---S--- 1 mpiroc mpiroc  4098 Sep 14  2011 search.html
--w---S--- 1 mpiroc mpiroc  7801 Sep 14  2011 software.html
dr-x------ 1 mpiroc mpiroc  2048 Sep  6  2011 styles/
--w---S--- 1 mpiroc mpiroc  5230 Sep 14  2011 tutorials.html
--w---S--- 1 mpiroc mpiroc  8138 Sep 15  2011 using-this-cd.html
```

I must be doing something wrong--surely the CD is meant to be read! What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems to be meant for windows (I say that because of the .bat file). But that is good news (kinda): The CD probably does not have permissions written in it. The permissions that it has were given by Ubuntu itself when it mounted

Comment: I mpiroc a user in your computer ?
If you umount and mount again via nautilus, does it work ?